# Is there an object that contains the parameters of a function?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, parameters

In a method that is so long that it scrolls off the screen. Just to make life easier as I program, if I want to refer to the variables of a class I can use the `Me` or `this` objects depending on which language I am using.

```
eg. Me.var1 = "Hello"
```

Is there an object (like `Me`) that would allow easy reference to the parameters of a function?

```
eg. params.par1 = "World"
```

Comment: why do you need anything like that? if we understand your need, we can suggest ways.

Comment: Just for ease of programming - if I am a long way down in a function I would like to see what parameters there are without having to scroll up.

Comment: So, you'd like something that works in Visual Studio's editor, not in the application itself?

Comment: Write shorter functions... :-)

Comment: Just use their ***names***. What could be shorter or easier than that?!?

Comment: I should add that, despite the smiley, that's a serious suggestion. Personally I've increased the size of text in my editor (13pt, if you care) as a reminder that, if I can't fit a function on screen at that size, it's probably too long.

Comment: Have you tried [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com)

Comment: @CJ7. Also, in the visual studio IDE, there is a little box at the top of the code editor that contains the function name, and also lists its parameter types and names.

Comment: Resharper would help you to extract loops and conditionals into private methods. Highlight the loop you want to extract, then hit ctrl r and ctrl m and it will show you what params it is going to use for the new method.

Comment: Shame that this is downvoted. Where would we be if we could not ask dumb questions? (no offence to the o.p.)

Comment: @Mark It's probably downvoted because it's not clear from the question exactly what he's asking. It *sounds* like he wants to do this at runtime, so he's getting answers about using reflection. But really, he just wants to do it in the IDE for simplicity while writing code. Totally different thing.

Answer (score 6):

There's no such feature in the language.  Local variables and method arguments are treated specially by the .NET jitter, they are *heavily* optimized at runtime.  Anything .NET would do, or you would do, to capture those variables would defeat such optimizations.

A very simple solution is to use Window + Split, it gives you two views on your code.  Scroll the top one to the method header, write your code in the bottom one.  You can adjust the splitter to give you more room in the bottom window.

Taking advantage of IntelliSense would be another way.  Prefix the argument names with a little string, like "par".  Then typing "par" in your code automatically gives you the list of argument names in the IntelliSense popup window.

These are however but band-aids for the real problem.  As soon as you find yourself reaching like this, your **first** thought should be to split up the code in the function to make it smaller.  There are some hard truths I discovered after thirty years of coding:

- Long methods have more bugs.  There's a metric for this, called "cyclomatic complexity".  The higher the number, the more likely that the code is broken.  Well supported by Visual Studio, this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2011/05/17/code-metrics-cyclomatic-complexity.aspx) is useful.
- Code should never be indented more than 3 levels deep.  By far the simplest way to discover that your cyclomatic complexity is getting out of hand without running a tool.
- A method should never be larger than what fits on the screen.  Any code that doesn't fit is a cognitive tax that produces compile errors and bugs.  There's a corollary to this, programmers with big monitors create more bugs.  The hard rule I use is one inspired by using DOS editors, a method should not have more than 25 lines of code.
- Wide code produces a special kind of bug, the nasty kind that you can't see.  Anything that's off the screen to the right is code that may have a bug that can take you a *long* time to discover.  VB.NET is especially prone to this kind of bug since it uses end-of-line as a statement terminator.  Much improved in VS2010 btw, the underscore is now optional in many cases.  Always break your line to avoid this kind of bug.
- Plan ahead and write *maintainable* code.  Maintained code is never smaller than the original.  If you already have trouble writing the original code then by definition you cannot maintain it.  You have to start out small.
- Always design first, code later.  Long methods are a strong indicator of not thinking about code long enough before you start coding.  In itself a strong bug inducer, in addition to writing correct code that just doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. It seems like you are hoping to use this to distinguish between parameter scope and class scope for function parameters and fields with the same name, unfortunately you can't. Either use different naming schemes, or do the following:

```
public class MyClass {
  private string myString;
  private int myInt;
  public MyClass(string myString) {
    this.myString = myString;
  }
  public int DoStuff(int myInt) {
    this.myInt += myInt;
    return this.myInt;
  }
}
```

to be really clear and avoid problems, you could change the names:

```
public class MyClass {
  private string m_myString;
  private int m_myInt;
  public MyClass(string myString) {
    m_myString = myString;
  }
  public int DoStuff(int myInt) {
    m_myInt += myInt;
    return m_myInt;
  }
}
```

And you should really start by writing a test before the code, then you can check that you haven't accidentally mixed things up in your code.

**Footnote**

*I include this as people coming to the title of this question may be looking for the following information.*

While you say

> Just for ease of programming - if I am a long way down in a function I would like to see what parameters there are without having to scroll up

In case you really want to look at your parameters from inside your code for other reasons then you need reflection. This is slow, and it's typical use would be to find a method, then reflect the parameters in that method. For a very comprehensive sample, see [MSDN - ParameterInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.aspx). The pertinent part of the code is:

```
foreach (MemberInfo mi in typeof(MyClass).GetMembers() )
{
  // If the member is a method, display information about its parameters. 
  if (mi.MemberType==MemberTypes.Method)
  {
  foreach ( ParameterInfo pi in ((MethodInfo) mi).GetParameters() )
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Parameter: Type={0}, Name={1}", pi.ParameterType, pi.Name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`GetParameters()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) reflection method

```
MethodInfo barMI = bar.GetMethod("Foo");
ParameterInfo[] pars = barMI.GetParameters();
foreach (ParameterInfo p in pars) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
}
```

You can use this in run time. But for your aim, I would try to refactor the number of functions and their names. I try to keep code length under 80 symbols per line and the number of lines in a class under 100. Which is not always possible, but it's a good objective to decouple stuff and keep classes simple.

Comment: this gives the names, but how about the values?

Comment: OP says. `Just for ease of programming - if I am a long way down in a function I would like to see what parameters there are without having to scroll up` he/she needs a VS extension:)

Comment: @I4V Yes and OP added that as a comment after I answered. For which I made an edit to make the class simpler. Not sure though if this answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: @oleksii I am not the downvoter. I justed wanted to point out that there is no programming answer to this question. A +1 just to offset.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to encapsulate your parameters in an object so you can just refer to that, and intellitype (or whatever predictive feature) would show you what properties you have available without having to scroll back up. Like this

```
public class MyParamObject{
    public string FirstParam {get;set;}
    public string SecondParam {get;set;}
}
```

Then you could change your method from

```
public void MyReallyOvergrownMethod(string firstParam, string secondParam){...
```

to

```
public void MyReallyOvergrownMethod(MyParamObject params){...
```

then you can use the params parameter like this in the method

```
//Deep inside the method
if(params.FirstParam == "SomeValue"{//Do something
```

This is a numpty solution to a problem that would be best solved by refactoring your method. Look at loops, and conditionals and get them out into seperate private methods that are named after what they do. Loads of stuff on this, if you search for cleancoders.

Answer (score 0):

In light of your comment "Just for ease of programming - if I am a long way down in a function I would like to see what parameters there are without having to scroll up": in Visual Studio, with code showing, just above the scrollbar there is a little bit you can grab and pull down to split the window. You can then have your function declaration visible in one pane and scroll as much as you like in the other. Or you can use Window menu->Split.